# Adding alert to swipeable row iOS 15

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a list of views with the new swipeActions method from iOS 15 beta, when I try to add a confirmation dialog (alert) when the user swipes on a row, I am getting an error that says

"Closure containing control flow statement cannot be used with result builder 'TableRowBuilder'"

Here is the code that results in this error.

```
var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(itemStore.items, id: \.id) { item in
                if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {    // Error appears here
                    ItemView(item: item)
                        .swipeActions() {
                            Button {
                                withAnimation { showingAlert.toggle() }
                            } .alert("Important message", isPresented: $showingAlert) {
                                Button("First") { }
                                Button("Second") { }
                                Button("Third") { }
                            } label: {
                                Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash")
                            }
                        }
                        .tint(.red)
                } else {
                    // Fallback on earlier versions
                    ItemView(item: item)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
Button {
    withAnimation { showingAlert.toggle() }
} .alert("Important message", isPresented: $showingAlert) {
    Button("First") { }
    Button("Second") { }
    Button("Third") { }
} label: {
    Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash")
}
```

`Button`'s initializer is actually `init(action:label:)`, which looks like this:

```
Button {
    withAnimation { showingAlert.toggle() }
} label: {
    Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash")
}
```

You added an extra `.alert` in between the other parameters. This doesn't work. Instead, put the `.alert` outside the `ForEach`, for example on the `List` (it's best for alerts to be at the top level, not nested inside any subviews).

```
struct ItemStore {
    var items: [String]
}
struct ContentView: View {
    let itemStore = ItemStore(items: [
        "Hi",
        "Hello"
    ])
    @State var showingAlert = false
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(itemStore.items, id: \.self) { item in
                if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
                    Text("Item: \(item)")
                        .swipeActions() {
                            Button {
                                withAnimation { showingAlert.toggle() }
                            } label: {
                                Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash")
                            }
                        }
                        .tint(.red)
                } else {
                    // Fallback on earlier versions
                    Text("Item: \(item)")
                }
            }
        } /// alert goes here!
        .alert("Important message", isPresented: $showingAlert) {
            Button("First") { }
            Button("Second") { }
            Button("Third") { }
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation! By the way the .alert(String, isPresented) method is only available for iOS 15 so you would have to make a check for ios version there as well (since its outside the other available conditional).

Comment: Great explanation ! Solved my issue too ! Thanks :)